# how to sort object with key value date as key

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have the following object which I would like to sort. the key is date field in Unix and I will need to keep the value for each key. the examples that I have seen get rid of the value but sort the key.

```
{
"1458345600000":598.15,
"1458432000000":498.77000000000004,
"1458604800000":598.4699999999999,
"1458691200000":598.2900000000001,
"1458777600000":598.26,
"1458864000000":697.79,
"1459206000000":598.21,
"1459292400000":598.2800000000001,
"1459638000000":598.74,
"1457481600000":566.88,
"1457568000000":466.02000000000004,
"1457654400000":470.36,
"1457740800000":481.25,
"1457827200000":484.74000000000007,
"1457913600000":575.8199999999999,
"1458000000000":498.83000000000004,
"1458086400000":498.76,
"1458172800000":598.73,
"1458259200000":598.93,
"1458518400000":499.03999999999996,
"1458950400000":498.14,
"1459036800000":498.78,
"1459119600000":498.65999999999997,
"1459378800000":598.66,
"1459465200000":598.95,
"1459551600000":497.05
}
```

The key is an integer value;

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following which still does not work

```
var map = arr_cssr[key];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
        Object.keys(map).sort((a,b) => parseInt(a) > parseInt(b));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
        var subarr = [];
        for ( var k in map) {
            console.log(moment.unix(parseInt(k)/1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD')); 
            subarr.push({
                0 : parseInt(k),
                1 : map[k]/count
            });
        }
```

**result**

```
{"1458345600000":595,"1458432000000":496,"1458604800000":595,"1458691200000":595,"1458777600000":595,"1458864000000":695,"1459206000000":596,"1459292400000":595,"1459638000000":597,"1459724400000":595,"1459810800000":695,"1457481600000":566,"1457568000000":463,"1457654400000":468,"1457740800000":480,"1457827200000":483,"1457913600000":574,"1458000000000":496,"1458086400000":496,"1458172800000":596,"1458259200000":596,"1458518400000":495,"1458950400000":495,"1459036800000":496,"1459119600000":496,"1459378800000":595,"1459465200000":596,"1459551600000":494}
{"1458345600000":595,"1458432000000":496,"1458604800000":595,"1458691200000":595,"1458777600000":595,"1458864000000":695,"1459206000000":596,"1459292400000":595,"1459638000000":597,"1459724400000":595,"1459810800000":695,"1457481600000":566,"1457568000000":463,"1457654400000":468,"1457740800000":480,"1457827200000":483,"1457913600000":574,"1458000000000":496,"1458086400000":496,"1458172800000":596,"1458259200000":596,"1458518400000":495,"1458950400000":495,"1459036800000":496,"1459119600000":496,"1459378800000":595,"1459465200000":596,"1459551600000":494}
2016-03-19
2016-03-20
2016-03-22
2016-03-23
2016-03-24
2016-03-25
2016-03-29
2016-03-30
2016-04-03
2016-04-04
2016-04-05
2016-03-09
2016-03-10
2016-03-11
2016-03-12
2016-03-13
2016-03-14
2016-03-15
2016-03-16
2016-03-17
2016-03-18
2016-03-21
2016-03-26
2016-03-27
2016-03-28
2016-03-31
2016-04-01
2016-04-02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to sort the keys then get the `value` from original object

```
var map = arr_cssr[key];
        map = Object.keys(map);
        map.sort(function(x, y) {
         if (x > y) return -1;
         if (x < y) return 1;
         if (x == y) return 0;
        });
        var subarr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            subarr.push({
                0 : parseInt(map[i]),
                1 : arr_cssr[key][map[i]]/count
            });
        }
```

Comment: please change then to the it is confusing " then get THE value"

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort an object. It's unordered. You can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead, or just sort its keys.

```
Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => a > b);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't makes any sense to sort a Javascript object having key value pairs. Though in array it does actually makes sense as you will be changing the index of the elements but in this object we don't want that.

Still if you want all the values sorted by keys you can use something like this:

```js
var data = {
  "1458345600000": 598.15,
  "1458432000000": 498.77000000000004,
  "1458604800000": 598.4699999999999,
  "1458691200000": 598.2900000000001,
  "1458777600000": 598.26,
  "1458864000000": 697.79,
  "1459206000000": 598.21,
  "1459292400000": 598.2800000000001,
  "1459638000000": 598.74,
  "1457481600000": 566.88,
  "1457568000000": 466.02000000000004,
  "1457654400000": 470.36,
  "1457740800000": 481.25,
  "1457827200000": 484.74000000000007,
  "1457913600000": 575.8199999999999,
  "1458000000000": 498.83000000000004,
  "1458086400000": 498.76,
  "1458172800000": 598.73,
  "1458259200000": 598.93,
  "1458518400000": 499.03999999999996,
  "1458950400000": 498.14,
  "1459036800000": 498.78,
  "1459119600000": 498.65999999999997,
  "1459378800000": 598.66,
  "1459465200000": 598.95,
  "1459551600000": 497.05
};

var valuesSorted = Object.keys(data).sort().map(function(el) {
  return data[el];
});

console.log(valuesSorted);
```

now `valuesSorted` will be array having all the values sorted by their respective `keys`. Though please consider changing the sort compare function according to your need.

Comment: Isn't that an alphanumeric sort?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = { ... };
var sorted = Object.keys(a).map(k=>parseInt(k)).sort((a,b)=>a-b).map(k=>a[k.toString()]);
```

Numeric sort with explicit type conversion.

Comment: this returned only the values

Comment: Right, but the key is right there for you to use.. that's k.

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = { };

map = Object.keys(map);

map.sort(function(x, y) {
 if (x > y) return -1;
 if (x < y) return 1;
 if (x == y) return 0;
});
```

Comment: this returned only the keys